# Scilab pointer function

Tags: scilab

I am working on converting code from MATLAB to scilab included here.

The `@` symbol is used as a memory pointer in MATLAB pointing to the location of the function `tst_callback`.

Scilab does not like this however. Is there a scilab equivalent for the `@`?

```
function test
    sysIDgui(@tst_callback)     
end

function tst_callback()
    disp("Hello Ron")
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is to pass a function as argument to another function. In Scilab, you don't need any special syntax.

Try it yourself. Define these two functions:

```
function y = applyFunction(f,x)
    y = f(x);
endfunction

function y = double(x)
    y = x * 2;
endfunction
```

Then test it on the console:

```
--> applyFunction(double,7)
 ans  =

   14.
```

**Note:** the main usage of `@` in MATLAB, is to create anonymous functions ([see documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html#btg5lbu-1)),  ones that are not defined in a separate file. As for Scilab, there is no way to create anonymous functions.

Comment: I see that I have made an error in presenting this question.

In my example the following will be an *.sci file that will do the computation.
In the function 'test' 'sysIDgui' is a separate sci file that contains all of the uicontrol layouts and formatting.

The purpose of the @tst_callback is to let the gui file find the function in a different file and execute it there. 

function test
    sysIDgui(@tst_callback)     
end

function tst_callback()
    disp("Hello Ron")
endfunction

Comment: @TheWenz Now you got me confused, because I don't know exactly what is your problem. Can you edit your original question?

Comment: Then you have to load the function. See exec function. Once you have loaded it, you can call it as usual.

Comment: Is also possible to pass variables by reference to functions? I would appreciate if you could also help me with the question I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060752/how-pass-variables-by-reference-to-a-scilab-function)